# Create Groups based on revenue and year in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a scenario to cover in SQL stated below.

Any help would be appreciated.

Segment all customers in the data using the following rules. The groups should be mutually exclusive i.e. one customer should fall only in one group and a higher-ranked group gets priority (ex. If a customer falls in group 1 and group 3 then group 1 gets priority)

- Group 1: Customers with >2000 total revenue in last 1-year
- Group 2: Customers with >2000 total revenue in last 2 years
- Group 3: Customers with >2000 total revenue in any 2 consecutive years (in the entire data provided)
- Group 4: Customers with <2000 in last 2 years
- Group 5: Customers with 0 revenue in the last 2 years

Comment: Sample data and expected results (as text) would help immensely, preferably `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements, as well as your current attempt

Comment: You can't do everything at once. I suggest you focus on writing a query for the first group. When you get that working, write another for the second. Repeat. That should help you understand how to achieve your actual goal.